# Threading ping in mininet

Tags: python, multithreading, ping, sdn, mininet

I want to launch two or many hosts simultaneously for pinging two others hosts with python in mininet, i do that and doesn't work

```
def simpleTest(h1,h2): 

    print (h1.cmd('ping -c5 %s' h2.IP()))
```

and main :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    net = Mininet(...)
    threads= 3 # three threads
    #....codes...... 
    for i in range(1, threads):
        hostsrc=net.hosts[i]
        hostdest=net.hosts[i+4]
        thread = threading.Thread(target=simpleTest(hostsrc,hostdest))
        jobs.append(thread)

    for j in jobs:
        j.start()
    for j in jobs:
        j.join()
    """
    codes ...
    """
```

Any solution for that please ...

Comment: What does _doesn’t work_ mean?

Comment: it's mean " not  simultaneously "

Comment: In concrete terms, what does that mean in your program. Does that mean there's an error?

Comment: There is no error but the ping is not in parallel state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked by adding args in this line ...

```
        thread = threading.Thread(target=simpleTest, args=(hostsrc,hostdest,))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you pass the `simpleTest` function as an argument, you are calling it. You should write the code like this:

```
thread = threading.Thread(target = simpleTest, args = (hostsrc, hostdest,))
```

Or using lambda:

```
thread = threading.Thread(target = lambda:simpleTest(hostsrc, hostdest))
```

The code you wrote passed the value None to the `target` parameter, since the `simpleTest` function returns no value, so nothing happened when calling the `start` method.